# FileStream.Write not Writing to File

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I'm passing some Base64 encoded strings through WCF, and I'm attempting to write them to a file. However, despite the fact that my FileStream object has a Length greater than 0, my file on disk remains empty.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Config.Instance.SharedSettings.SaveDir + StudyInstance.StudyId + "\\tmp.ext", FileMode.Create);

EncodeBlock eb = new EncodeBlock();

while (eb.Part != eb.OfParts || eb.OfParts == 0)
{
    eb.ToDecode = ps.StudyService.GetInstancePart(StudyInstance, s, eb.Part+ 1, Config.Instance.ClientSettings.AppData);
    eb = Base64Encoder.Decode(eb);
    fs.Write(eb.ToEncode, 0, eb.ToEncode.Length);
}

fs.Close();
```

`eb.ToEncode`'s length is always greater than 0, `fs.Length` is always greater than 0, and yet my `"tmp.ext"` file is created, but remains empty. `fs.CanWrite` is always also true.

Comment: How are verifying that the file is empty?

Comment: This may seem like a no-brainer, but have you debugged the code to ensure you're actually entering your WHILE block?

Comment: It was a no-brainer. Final solution was for me to look at the right directory's `"tmp.ext"` file... don't ask, it's been one of those days, but thanks all for the help!

Comment: Marginally related, you might want to consider using Path.Combine instead of simple string concatenation for creating the file name. In this instance it'll make your code longer, but it will also make the code more representative of your intent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried calling FileStream.Flush?

Call it just before you Close the stream.

You should also use a "using" statement to ensure the stream is cleaned up.

Comment: It's my understanding that closing a FileStream automatically flushes the buffer. You're right about the `using` statement

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
var streamBytes = myMemoryStream.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(myFilePath, streamBytes);
```